# How to match and replace entire word that contains substring using Javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match and replace the entire word that contains a substring using Javascript.

This is my code so far:

```
var final = ""
var n, a = [], walk = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
const searchWordPattern = new RegExp(searchWord, 'i');

while(n = walk.nextNode()) {
  a.push(n);
  n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.replace(searchWordPattern, "--");
  final = final.concat(n.nodeValue);
}
```

This partially works. It finds the word I'm searching for and removes it. But if the search word is conjugated in any way, that gets left behind. I'd like for the regex to match the entire word where the substring is found. And remove it all. What do I need to change?

EDIT

I tried using the below answer, but it doesn't appear to do anything different for either the \w or \S variations. Here is the code I am using:

```
var final = ""
var n, a = [], walk = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
const searchWordPattern = new RegExp('\S*' + searchWord + '\S*', 'i');

while(n = walk.nextNode()) {
  a.push(n);
  n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.replace(searchWordPattern, "--");
  final = final.concat(n.nodeValue);
}
```

The result is that the searchWord is replaced by the "--" string, but if it is conjugated it doesn't include the other characters. So if "look" is the searchWord, the result of the regex is "--ing". I want it to just be "--".

Comment: You'll need to change your searchWordPattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the regex, so that instead of just searching for the word:

```
new RegExp(searchWord, 'i');
```

You can also search for any surrounding "word" characters:

```
new RegExp('\\w*' + searchWord + '\\w*', 'i');
```

Or all the non-whitespace characters:

```
new RegExp('\\S*' + searchWord + '\\S*', 'i');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a great answer. For a first post, this is probably the best one I've ever seen.

Comment: @CrackpotCrocodile Thanks for your answer. I tried the code, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Please see my edit above. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Lizza Which string are you using? Does it has special characters?

Comment: @Lizza You need to double-escape. That is, you need to run `new RegExp('\\S*' + searchWord + '\\S*', 'i');`. Inside a string `'\S'` is just `'S'`, while `'\\S'` will give `\S`. Try this: `console.log(new RegExp('\S*look\S*', 'i'), new RegExp('\\S*look\\S*', 'i'));` (run it on your browser's console)